# How does console.error work internally?

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to print error stack trace in console.error(errorObject.stack) and the same in console.log(errorObject.stack) the difference is console.log shows less information than console.error() for eg,

For  ***console.log()*** it prints:

```
    >console.log(error.stack)
    >VM93392:1 Error: Requested Resource was not mapped.
    at Object._createErrorObject (TestUtil.js:237)
    at Object.mapRestResponseError (TestUtil.js:231)
    at TestDataSource.js:90
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1670)
    at Module.check (require.js:971)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1212)
    at Module.init (require.js:870)
    at Object.require (require.js:1472)
    at requirejs (require.js:1754)
    at child.openRestError (TestDataSource.js:94)
    at child.openRestErrorStatus (TestDataSource.js:85)
    at options.error (TestDataSource.js:58)
    at options.error (MyUtil.js:5375)
    at Object.options.error (MyUtil.js:448)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at done (jquery-1.9.1.js:8076)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.9.1.js:8598)
```

where as for ***console.error*** it prints log trace starting from initialization:

```
    >console.error(error.stack)
    >VM93423:1 Error: Requested Resource was not mapped.
    at Object._createErrorObject (TestUtil.js:237)
    at Object.mapRestResponseError (TestUtil.js:231)
    at TestDataSource.js:90
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1670)
    at Module.check (require.js:971)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1212)
    at Module.init (require.js:870)
    at Object.require (require.js:1472)
    at requirejs (require.js:1754)
    at child.openRestError (TestDataSource.js:94)
    at child.openRestErrorStatus (TestDataSource.js:85)
    at options.error (TestDataSource.js:58)
    at options.error (MyUtil.js:5375)
    at Object.options.error (MyUtil.js:448)
    at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)
    at done (jquery-1.9.1.js:8076)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.9.1.js:8598)
    (anonymous) @   VM93423:1
    _createErrorObject  @   TestUtil.js:237
    mapRestResponseError    @   TestUtil.js:231
    (anonymous) @   TestDataSource.js:90
    execCb  @   require.js:1670
    check   @   require.js:971
    enable  @   require.js:1212
    init    @   require.js:870
    require @   require.js:1472
    requirejs   @   require.js:1754
    _openResponseRestError  @   TestDataSource.js:94
    _openRestResponseErrorStatus    @   TestDataSource.js:85
    options.error   @   TestDataSource.js:58
    options.error   @   MyUtil.js:5375
    options.error   @   MyUtil.js:448
    fire    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
    fireWith    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
    done    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:8076
    callback    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:8598
    XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
    send    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
    ajax    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
    RESTDataSource.sync @   MyUtil.js:3820
    callback    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:8598
    XMLHttpRequest.send (async) (------> same trace till this part <----)
    send    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
    ajax    @   jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
    RESTDataSource.sync @   MyUtil.js:3820
    sync    @   MyUtil.js:4317
    sync    @   TestDataSource.js:89
    sync    @   MyUtil.js:3407
    fetch   @   MyUtil.js:3236
    processRbaUrl   @   MyUtil.js:13564
    makeRBACall @   ConfigureService.js:587
    initialize  @   ConfigureService.js:570
    initialize  @   CartView.js:31
    wrapper @   MyUtil.js:854
    Backbone.View   @   backbone.js:985
    constructor @   MyUtil.js:11989
    ....
```

Everything is same for console.log and console.error till ***XMLHttpRequest.send (async)*** in console.error after that it has more information than console.log.

Can anyone please tell me why is such behavior?

Comment: `console.error` appears to append a trace of the location where `console.error` was called from. It has nothing to do with the logged value (a stack string in your case).

Comment: @Bergi Can I get the same trace in console.log?

Comment: You don't. But you can use `console.trace`.

Comment: In my production env console.trace and console.error are not working only console.log is working so I need to use console.log. Is there any other way than console.error or console.trace to get the full stack trace?

Comment: Sounds like a production environment that does not support stack traces.

Comment: yes I can only trace till **XMLHttpRequest.send (async)** after that there are is no stack..